# Using optionals as filters only if not nil

Tags: swift

Lets say I have a class in Swift called MyObject which has a bunch of String properties (for example) `name`, `hometown`, `favoriteColor`. And I have an array of MyObject, and I basically want to filter the array based on **certain** properties. Thus when I define my filtering parameters, I define them as optionals, and if the optional is nil, I assume I do not want to filter along that property. How would I write this code elegantly for more than one property?

```
var list: [MyObject] = [some array here]

class MyObject {
    var name: String
    var hometown: String
    var favouriteColor: String

    init(name: String, hometown: String, favouriteColor: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.hometown = hometown
        self.favouriteColor = favouriteColor        
    }
 }
```

That is the class above. Let's say I am writing a function in the playground to filter. I can write this unelegantly as such.

```
func filter(name: String?, hometown: String?, favouriteColor: String?) {
    var filteredObjects : [MyObject]? = list
    if (name != null) {
       filteredObjects = filteredObjects.filter($0.name == name)
    }
    if (hometown != null) {
       filteredObjects = filteredObjects.filter($0.hometown == hometown)
    }

}
```

Maybe I would call the above as such `filter(name: nil, hometown: nil, favouriteColor: "blue")`

I guess what I'm asking is if what I proposed above will even work, and if so, is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Can you show of the "not elegant" code that you have so that we know exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Sweeper I would have to create several if-statements (one for each property to check if nil). If property is not nil, I would filter by that property and then continue to the next property.

Comment: That is still very unclear in my opinion. Can you show some example code. A [mcve] would be best.

Answer (score 1):

Given your class

```
class MyObject {
    let name: String?
    let hometown: String?
    let favouriteColor: String?

    init(name: String?, hometown: String?, favouriteColor: String?) {
        self.name = name
        self.hometown = hometown
        self.favouriteColor = favouriteColor        
    }
}
```

and your array

```
let elms: [MyObject] = []
```

### Solution 1

You could do the filtering like this

```
let filtered = elms.filter { $0.name != nil && $0.hometown != nil && $0.favouriteColor != nil }
```

### Solution 2

Or you can move the logic inside your class

```
class MyObject {
    let name: String?
    let hometown: String?
    let favouriteColor: String?

    init(name: String?, hometown: String?, favouriteColor: String?) {
        self.name = name
        self.hometown = hometown
        self.favouriteColor = favouriteColor
    }

    var allFieldsPopulated: Bool {
        return name != nil && hometown != nil && favouriteColor != nil
    }
}
```

now you can simply write

```
let filtered = elms.filter { $0.allFieldsPopulated }
```

### Performance (Short Circuiting Evaluation)

The right side of an **and** `&&` expression is evaluated only if the left side I `true`.

So writing

```
name != nil && hometown != nil && favouriteColor != nil
```

means that if name is `nil` only this part `name != nil` of the expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a nicer way to write the condition, here are a couple of suggestions:

```
func filter(name: String?, hometown: String?, favouriteColor: String?) 
{
    filteredObjects = list.filter 
    { 
           $0.name           == name           ?? $0.name
        && $0.hometown       == hometown       ?? $0.hometown
        && $0.favouriteColor == favouriteColor ?? $0.favouriteColor
    }
}

func filter(name: String?, hometown: String?, favouriteColor: String?) 
{
    func criteria(_ value:String?, matches field:String) -> Bool
    { return value == nil || value! == field }

    filteredObjects = list.filter 
    { 
          criteria(name,           matches: $0.name)
       && criteria(hometown,       matches: $0.hometown)
       && criteria(favouriteColor, matches: $0.favouriteColor)
    }
}
```